# How to post array of hidden values

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a model which contains a list

```
public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
```

In my page i read them in as hidden

```
 if (Model?.Client?.Properties != null)
     {
         foreach (var property in Model.Client.Properties)
         {
             @Html.HiddenFor(x => property.Id)
             @Html.HiddenFor(x => property.Value)
             @Html.HiddenFor(x => property.Key)
         }
     }
```

I can see in the souce on the page that they are being filled out

```
<input id="property_Value" name="property.Value" type="hidden" value="2018-04-17T12:14:36.1126718&#x2B;00:00" />
<input id="property_Key" name="property.Key" type="hidden" value="CreateDate" />
<input id="property_Id" name="property.Id" type="hidden" value="5" />
<input id="property_Value" name="property.Value" type="hidden" value="2018-04-17T12:14:36.1136756&#x2B;00:00" />
<input id="property_Key" name="property.Key" type="hidden" value="UpdateDate" />
<input id="property_Id" name="property.Id" type="hidden" value="6" />
<input id="property_Value" name="property.Value" type="hidden" value="21880" />
<input id="property_Key" name="property.Key" type="hidden" value="FiscalId" />
```

But when the form is posted the values of the other items are posted but the properties list is null.  I am guessing it has something to do with the id or the name of the hiden fields.

Update:

Trying with a for loop.

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < Model.Client.Properties.Count() ; i++)
         {
             @Html.Hidden($"properties[{i}].id", Model.Client.Properties[i].Id)
             @Html.Hidden($"properties[{i}].value", Model.Client.Properties[i].Value)
             @Html.Hidden($"properties[{i}].key", Model.Client.Properties[i].Key)

         }
```

Gives

```
 <input id="properties_1__key" name="properties[1].key" type="hidden" value="UpdateDate" />
 <input id="properties_2__id" name="properties[2].id" type="hidden" value="6" />
 <input id="properties_2__value" name="properties[2].value" type="hidden" value="21880" />
 <input id="properties_2__key" name="properties[2].key" type="hidden" value="FiscalId" />
```

Doesnt work either

Comment: Well you have duplicate `id`s here which is invalid HTML. This is usually caused by looping with a `foreach`, better to use a classic `for()` loop and index the properties.

Comment: Ok i agree with you there but @Html.HiddenFor(x => property.Id) doesn't take a name it makes it itself.

Comment: Yes, but if you did `@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Client.Properties[0].Id)` you would see valid HTML and likely the correct data being posted.

Comment: WOOT that did it your awesome want to submit an answer?  I have been messing with this for an hour!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `foreach` loop loses the context of the property. Instead you need to use a classic `for` loop and index the properties. For example:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < Model.Client.Properties.Count() ; i++)
{
    @Html.Hidden(x => Model.Client.Properties[i].Id)
    @Html.Hidden(x => Model.Client.Properties[i].Value)
    @Html.Hidden(x => Model.Client.Properties[i].Key)
}
```